# Probability of dependent events in an MMORPG

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I've been playing a MMORPG recently and have learnt basic probability to figure out how much money I will realistically need for upgrading different items.

I have a sword to upgrade. Normally when you try to upgrade the item and it fails, it will break. For this sword, each stage of upgrading has a different chance of succeeding, the formula for which is `1-n*0.1+0.1`. So to upgrade from +0 to +1, the probability of success of 1, from +1 to +2 it's 0.9 and so on up to the maximum upgrade which is from +8 to +9 which has a 0.1 chance. That's fair enough and I got `1*0.9*0.8*0.7*0.6*0.5*0.4*0.3*0.2 = 0.0036288` to upgrade from +0 to +9.

However, there is an item that is making my head hurt. The Blessing Scroll makes it so that if you upgrade with this item and the upgrade fails, the sword will go down by one level. For example, if you try to upgrade from +5 to +6 and fail, the sword will go down to +4.

An additional issue with working this out is that each upgrade stage has different costs associated with it. +5 to +6 will require different items than +8 to +9

How would I approach working this out? I have googled for dependant events but didn't come across anything like this. Decision trees become massive when there are so many stages and they all link to their previous one, and I don't know other techniques that could help.

Comment: First, you need to decide what you want to find out. If you have infinite Blessing Scrolls and resources, you will *eventually* reach +9 with probability 1 (the sword will never break, so there is no chance of failure). You may ask how many resources you need on average, or what the probability of failing with a fixed number of resources is. You are right that, unless the amount of resources is really low, the problem quickly becomes too hard to do by hand and you will need to program the computations.

Comment: Does the blessing scroll work for one attempt of upgrading? Or does it last, like, 10 minutes?

Comment: That makes sense, my initial idea was on how many resources I would need on average. However, there are variable number of Blessing Scrolls and upgrade items required, which makes this difficult to wrap my head around

Comment: One time use, so one attempt at upgrading = 1 blessing scroll

Comment: I have figured out how to calculate the expected cost of acquiring a +9 sword and choose the best strategy (when to use the scroll, when to not use the scroll) to do it. However, It would be quite long and annoying to describe, so I don't want to do it. Sorry :( I can say shortly that first you need to figure out the best strategy and the expected cost of going from having +1 to having +2, then do the same from having +2 to having +3, then the same from having +3 to having +4, etc.

Comment: I have a found an identical question asked https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296592/probability-of-reaching-target-after-n-tries-with-regression-on-failure?rq=1 Interestingly enough, it is the exact same item with the Blessing Scroll problem, however worded more accurately. There are many answers so I would advise to visit that question instead.

Comment: I hope it was a fun problem to solve! I'll take your advice on and the answer I posted below and go from there, much appreciated.